# converting pom to build.gradle

Tags: maven, gradle

I am trying to convert plugin section in pom.xml file to gradle. How can I keep below code in build.gradle.

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <imageName>imagex</imageName>
                <baseImage>java</baseImage>
                <entryPoint>["java", "-jar", 
                  "/${project.build.finalName}.jar"]</entryPoint>
                <dockerDirectory>src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory} 
                        </directory>

                  <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                        <include>**/Dockerfile</include>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
                <imageTags>
                    <imageTag>${project.version}</imageTag>
                </imageTags>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Hello. Consider adding what you have in the gradle build file so far. Other than that the question looks good to me.